Apache POI 4.1.1 - Why is this fillPatternType error showing up?
I am getting the following error:
NameError: global name 'FillPatternType' is not defined
From this code:
oStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.index) oStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
What could be causing this? Please ask if any further information is needed. Thanks in advance!
I have tried using the Fill Patern argument as 1, but it also returned an error. I need to have a cell with a background color.

Did you add the import for FillPatternType ?

I have import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType, I dont know if that includes the enum now that I think about it.

I finally solved it. Turns out from org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel import FillPatternType and import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType is not the same.

Solution: import FillPatternType the following way:
from org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel import FillPatternType

